# Loki OpenGL issue with VMWare Workstation 12.5

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel, virtualization

I'm struggling to get VMWare Workstation 12.5 to enable 3D support for guest Windows VMs.
Currently I see an error telling me I need to update my drivers.
Google has suggested using a drivers utility in system settings but I don't have that panel in Loki.
I'm using Intel Corporation Broadwell U Integrated Graphics (rev09) and it would appear that the new Intel driver update utility for Ubuntu doesnt work with Elementary OS.
Any advice appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Virtual machines aren't well supported on elementary OS, but you should be able to install Intel drivers at least. I'm not sure what errors you received that you couldn't do the install on elementary OS.

As for the drivers utility, I think you want:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-gtk
```

Comment: Intel Graphics drivers are inside the kernel. He could install `intel-microcode` so maybe it gets some update.

Also, you can "tell" the intel driver utility that you are using ubuntu so that it installs. But I dont remember the correct procedure.